# How to create datasource in Weblogic using java

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I need to write a java code to create datasource in Weblogic using APIs. I found an API from Weblogic. But I am not able to find any sample implementation. Can someone please help me here? I m trying to use below API:

```
   DataSourceManager dsManager = DataSourceManager.getInstance();
   dsManager.createAndStartDataSource(jdbcImpl, appName, moduleName, compName, jdbcCtx, classLoader)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have to use java for this? how about using a python wlst script with a properties file (which you can alter later) instead?

Comment: It would be better if I can use Weblogic API. WLST script is last option.

Comment: try this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jdbc/programming.html#1049692

Comment: or this: http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS00/SWT/BEA/documentation/docs51/classdocs/conn_pools.html#635241 (see Creating a dynamic connection pool section)

Comment: or http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_weblogic_datasources_jmx.htm

Answer (score -1):

You need use WLST script interface management for that operation as described on that snippet:

```
   3:  import java.net.UnknownHostException;
   4:  import org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter;
   5:   
   6:  import weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter;
   7:   
   8:  public class DataSourceCreator {
   9:   
  10:      static InteractiveInterpreter interpreter = null;
  11:      private String weblogicPassword;
  12:      private String weblogicUserName;
  13:      private StringBuffer wlst_script;
  14:   
  15:      public DataSourceCreator(String weblogicUserName, String weblogicPassword) {
  16:          interpreter = new WLSTInterpreter();
  17:          this.weblogicUserName = weblogicUserName;
  18:          this.weblogicPassword = weblogicPassword;
  19:   
  20:      }
  21:   
  22:      /**
  23:       * connect to weblogic
  24:       */
  25:      private void connect() {
  26:          wlst_script.append("connect('" + this.weblogicUserName + "','" + this.weblogicPassword
  27:                  + "')");
  28:      }
  29:   
  30:      /**
  31:       * creates the data source script
  32:       * 
  33:       * @param dbpassword
  34:       * @param dbuser
  35:       * @param dsname
  36:       * @param jndiname
  37:       * @param dburi
  38:       * @param dbdrivername
  39:       */
  40:      private void createDataSourceScript(String dbpassword, String dbuser, String dsname,
  41:              String jndiname, String dburi, String dbdrivername) {
  42:   
  43:          int timeout = 100000;
  44:          int maxcapacity = 100;
  45:   
  46:          // substitute your server name here "SERVER_NAME" i.e the target.
  47:          wlst_script.append("cd('Servers/SERVER_NAME')\n");
  48:          wlst_script.append("target=cmo\n");
  49:          wlst_script.append("cd('../..')\n");
  50:          wlst_script.append("jdbcSystemResource = create('" + dsname + "','JDBCSystemResource')\n");
  51:          wlst_script.append("theJDBCResource = jdbcSystemResource.getJDBCResource()\n");
  52:          wlst_script.append("theJDBCResource.setName('" + dsname + "')\n");
  53:          wlst_script
  54:                  .append("connectionPoolParams = theJDBCResource.getJDBCConnectionPoolParams()\n");
  55:          wlst_script.append("connectionPoolParams.setConnectionReserveTimeoutSeconds(int('"
  56:                  + timeout + "'))\n");
  57:   
  58:          // maximum connections that can be made
  59:          wlst_script.append("connectionPoolParams.setMaxCapacity(int('" + maxcapacity + "'))\n");
  60:          // query to execute using ds to test if its successfull
  61:          wlst_script.append("connectionPoolParams.setTestTableName('SQL SELECT 1 FROM DUAL')\n");
  62:   
  63:          // update data source params
  64:          wlst_script.append("dsParams = theJDBCResource.getJDBCDataSourceParams()\n");
  65:          wlst_script.append("dsParams.addJNDIName('" + jndiname + "')\n");
  66:   
  67:          wlst_script.append("driverParams = theJDBCResource.getJDBCDriverParams()\n");
  68:          wlst_script.append("driverParams.setUrl('" + dburi + "')\n");
  69:          wlst_script.append("driverParams.setDriverName('" + dbdrivername + "')\n");
  70:          wlst_script.append("driverParams.setPassword('" + dbpassword + "')\n");
  71:   
  72:          wlst_script.append("driverProperties = driverParams.getProperties()\n");
  73:          wlst_script.append("proper = driverProperties.createProperty('user')\n");
  74:          wlst_script.append("proper.setValue('" + dbuser + "')\n");
  75:          wlst_script.append("proper1 = driverProperties.createProperty('DatabaseName')\n");
  76:          wlst_script.append("proper1.setValue('" + dburi + "')\n");
  77:          wlst_script.append("jdbcSystemResource.addTarget(target)\n");
  78:      }
  79:   
  80:      /**
  81:       * @param wlst_script
  82:       */
  83:      private void saveActivateAndDisconnect() {
  84:          // save , activate changes and disconnect
  85:          wlst_script.append("save()\n");
  86:          wlst_script.append("activate(block='true')\n");
  87:          wlst_script.append("disconnect()\n");
  88:      }
  89:   
  90:      /**
  91:       * start edit
  92:       * 
  93:       * @param wlst_script
  94:       */
  95:      private void startEdit() {
  96:          wlst_script.append("edit()\n");
  97:          wlst_script.append("startEdit()\n");
  98:      }
  99:   
 100:      public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {
 101:   
 102:          // weblogic related
 103:          String weblogicUserName = "username";
 104:          String weblogicPassword = "password";
 105:   
 106:          DataSourceCreator dsCreator = new DataSourceCreator(weblogicUserName, weblogicPassword);
 107:   
 108:          dsCreator.connect();
 109:          dsCreator.startEdit();
 110:          String sid = "sidofdb"; // sid of db
 111:          String ipaddress = "10.8.11.16"; // ip addres
 112:          String dbpassword = "password"; // database password
 113:          String dbuser = "username"; // db user name
 114:          String dsname = "datasourcename"; // your data source name
 115:          String jndiname = "jdbc/" + dsname; // jndi name for ds
 116:          String dburi = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + ipaddress + ":1521:" + sid;
 117:          String dbdrivername = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
 118:   
 119:          dsCreator.createDataSourceScript(dbpassword, dbuser, dsname, jndiname, dburi, dbdrivername);
 120:          dsCreator.saveActivateAndDisconnect();
 121:   
 122:          try {
 123:              // execute the script created above
 124:              interpreter.exec(dsCreator.wlst_script.toString());
 125:          } finally {
 126:              // disconnect even if there is exception
 127:              interpreter.exec("disconnect()\n");
 128:          }
 129:   
 130:      }
 131:   
 132:  }
```

Comment: Hi,

Will this below snippet connect to remote server? I think we need to pass IP and port of remote server also.

    wlst_script.append("connect('" + this.weblogicUserName + "','" + this.weblogicPassword + "')");

Comment: Correct. You need replace the connect string and add the link and port for server, for example, the connect string on that post: https://rathinasaba.wordpress.com/tag/connect-to-admin-server-using-wlst/ or reference on oracle docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_scripting/reference.html.

Comment: Thanks, can you please suggest some way to delete datasource also?

Comment: It's easy you have search on Oracle Documentation one session named delete editing command here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1003987, after you need implement one method for delete resource similar one creating resource. This work is your friend. Much details that that it's impossible now. Good work.